# In a world with two systems of magic, why is one system not dominant in some countries?

Tags: magic

Magic arises from collective belief - if enough people believe that the effect will happen, then it will. For example, if enough people are trying to get an airship to fly and believe they can do it, then up it goes into the sky. This is system 1.

Magic arises from the use and combination of items imbued with power. These items have power whether you believe they do or not. For example, if you tacitly believe that the potion of agonizing burning won't burn you that doesn't stop you from catching fire when you drink it. This is system 2.

In the Northlands magical items are exceedingly rare, but they do exist. Long ago the first people saw the magic in an item they found and then realized that they can make other magic happen. So system 1 arose from system 2 - someone saw magic happening, didn't understand that it was limited only to that one object, believed hard enough and got other magic to happen.

In the Southlands magical items are rare but not exceedingly so. A middle class family might own one or two. The magic in the Southlands is based almost entirely on these items, even though the belief-based system will still work there.

It's simple enough to explain why the Northlanders rely on their belief-based system - items are rare, trade with the south is hard, and the belief-based system works. But why would the Southlanders not also develop a strong tradition of belief-based magic? From a pure economic standpoint it doesn't make sense - rare items are harder to come by and use than just believing hard enough.

A few constraints:

1. I don't want the story to involve some kind of thought-police or anything like that. People in the South are free to develop belief-based magic, they just don't do it much.
2. System 2 really is free of the belief-based magic. I see it as the fundamental magic that underlies everything, and the belief-based stuff builds on it.
3. The world is vaguely steam/clockpunk, so travel between North and South is possible but generally difficult. Thus, there are some Northerners in the South and vice versa, and ideas and items flow as freely as they can. This means that everyone in the South knows that belief-based magic can work, and the rich in the North can afford the exorbitant costs of importing magical items.

So...why doesn't the South believe?

Comment: In general questions about why people do a thing aren't the best fit for this site. Given how many variables go into any human decision, and how little we know about your world this question has far too many equally valid answers. Consider how often political decisions are influenced by who's friends with the ruler at a particular moment in time.

Comment: VTC, opinion based. I think this is straying into figuring out your plot point, instead of "world building", asking us to invent a *reason* for you, after you have excluded the obvious reasons. The most obvious reason is the South just believes so much that magic **must** be object-based that they are convinced the North is just lying, or is mistaken, maybe it is something they eat or an unseen mineral in their water. They don't believe because their belief in object-based magic is firmly in place, no matter what the North says. But you have ruled that out.

Comment: If I'm a Northmage and I go to the South, do I need to acquire sufficiently convincing paraphernalia to make my magic work?  Do an Australomancer's thaumatools work North of the border if nobody knows what they are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**They Believe in Science.**

In the South everyone learns basic machinery at school. They use this machinery to make their Type 2 magic items do what they want.

They also use it for non-magical tinkering like clocks and hydraulic parasols and other steampunk stuff. This is where they develop the belief in a rational world where you can arrange simple elements to get a more complex device.

The most common magic item is a marble that does nothing other than produce light/heat/vibration. The marble is used as a power source for whatever machine you need at the time.

People build and repair their own machines and expect a look at the circuitry of someone else's train before they step on board.

This means the "unexplainable" magic of Type 1 does not go down well since there is no circuitry to inspect.

Comment: Downvote because of blatant anti-parasol bias.

Comment: I like this one, I think it contains the seeds of a good way forward for me

Answer (score 2):

While tales by word of mouth might convey the possibility of it happening it could be dismissed without empirical proof for sceptical minds. System 1 is not necessarily something that has been bred into the social fabric of the South as it may have been in the North.

If you had a toaster that made toast for you and toasters were common enough that you would have access to toast, even if you didnt know how a toaster worked, would you seek to refine it by believing real hard that the toast would be made better? Would you give much credence to tales of new and improved toast made by believing in it hard enough? Even if you believed it was possible how much effort would you go to when you had good enough without trying?

The world is full of people who know they could do better if they tried harder, did more, had more faith. But good enough without effort can be the path of least resistance.

System 1 arises from appreciating the value of rare items, people striving to maximise and innovate the use of rare items. Making diamonds shine. Once it becomes embedded as a cultural value then it becomes a path of less resistance.

I think this was explored somewhat in the idea of the Foundation series as a huge civilization of great power and resources crumbled under its own weight while the resource deprived Foundation had to innovate.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone in the South knows, and therefore believes, that the Northerners do magic differently, and therefore they can't do it the same way.

It's not like you can believe what you want.  Evidence, suggestions, and conformity shape your beliefs.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the south originally did believe in and use the belief based magic but a horrible tragedy forever soured then to it.

For example the southerners we're using a belief powered airship when an enemy propaganda campaign lowered beliefs enough to cause it to catastrophically crash killing thousands.

Or a belief based "power plant" melts down like a nuclear reactor.

Ever since that event the southerners see the belief based magic as unreliable and a national security risk.